# Webpack Import Ignore CSS

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, dependencies, dependency-management

I'm importing a JS file with Webpack (2), e.g.

```
import Test from 'XYZ/test';
```

In the imported file `test.js` I'm loading a CSS file, e.g.:

```
import './test.css';
```

Now, in my first above mentioned import I want to import `test.js` but not the css file that is imported from the file itself. So I just want to import JavaScript and ignore the CSS from the imported file.

**Is this possible in any way?**

Comment: When you import a file you import its dependencies in the same time. What you really want to do ? Build your web app without css ?

Comment: Import one single component without CSS.

Comment: Why not removing css rules in webpackconfig and adding ignoring rule for .css ?

Comment: I want to compile CSS in general. Just not for this single import to avoid redundant CSS.

Comment: My idea is to split `test.js` into 2 separate files, one with the `js` only and the other that will import that js & css.

Comment: Thanks @FelixMosheev. This is what I'm doing currently. However, I was hoping that there is another way, maybe by passing e.g. a query parameter or something like that.

Comment: Maybe you can use `ignore-loader` just for that import.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-loader